# Spring MVC HTTP Status 404 error when running on Server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller

I have been following an online tutorial in order to learn the basics of Spring MVC, and am running into some issues when I attempt to run the project on a local Tomcat server. I have read multiple discussions on here already, but cannot find the solution amongst the current answers which is why I am asking. The tutorial I am following is utilizing Eclipse, whereas I am using intellij, there there could have been an error on my part in the overall project set up as well.

Whenever I attempt to run my project I get a HTTP Status not found - 404 error. I was able to successfully get my main-menu page to load by including it in welcome-file-list in my xml file, but I want my controllers to be scanned in order to determine which jsp file to pull from. Below is my code:

Here is my spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is myweb.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <absolute-ordering />

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/view/main-menu.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    -->


</web-app>
```

Here is my HomeController.java file

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "main-menu";
    }
}
```

Here is my main-menu.jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<H2>Spring MVC Demo - Home Page</H2>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is an image of my project structure:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2akd.png)

Here is a picture of how I have my Tomcat server setup:

[Run Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylTlZ.png)

Thank you all in advance. I really appreciate the help with this. I realize it is probably a simple answer, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: Where is the beans configuration? is this spring boot app? you should configure your beans using configuration class or XML file

Comment: If you're learning Spring, then you should learn how to do things in the modern way, with Spring Boot (and preferably Thymeleaf instead of JSP). 100% of your XML is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will look into just using Spring Boot. I am using a Udemy class that is over 61 hours that is a few years old and has been updated with Spring Boot. The format of the class has been to teach using an xml file, than xml & annotations, and finally all Java code. I think I will maybe dump the course and just use documentation on the Spring website.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run HomeController.java file.
Run as click on spring-mvc-demo
Do not attempt to run the JSP files directly. This will not work due to MVC.
You need to access the correct URL, localhost:8080/spring-mvc-demo/